# How to encrypt a password in SHA1 in Extjs

Tags: extjs, sha1

in an application in Extjs I need to encrypt the password I read from submitting a login form in SHA1 mode, I could not find any function in Extjs that does this. Can you give me information on how I can encrypt this password in SHA1?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a proper ExtJs function to encrypt passwords.. You can use vanilla JS and [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) in order to do so, for example:

```js
const hash = CryptoJS.SHA1("Message");
console.log(hash.toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```